# How to set absolute colour ranges in seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

All - I have the following code to plot a heat map:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.pivot_table(df.round({'DataA':1}), index='Position',columns='Start',  values='DataA', aggfunc= 'sum')
    data = data.fillna(0)
    import matplotlib.colors as colors

    cmap, norm = colors.from_levels_and_colors([-15000, -500, -10,10,500,10000,100000], ['red','orange','white','green', 'lime','blue'])


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, fmt='g', linewidths=.5, ax=ax, cbar=True,cmap=cmap,norm=norm).set_title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: Plot]

You will see that in the second column there is an all blank cell which should show the value `11786.2` however I cant see it. How come all values over `10000` dont show and what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For some weird reason your 'blue' band is missing (also in the colorbar). Do you have recent versions of matplotlib and seaborn installed? In my quick test with toy data the blue parts appear as to be expected.  Do you have the same problem if you restart your environment?

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. Yeah I'm not sure why its doing it. Im using `Jupyter Notebook` through Anaconda and these are my imports:
 `pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns`

Comment: To see the version numbers:  `import seaborn as sns; print(sns.__version__)` and  `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` should print something like `0.10.1`and
`3.2.1`. If your versions are older than `0.10` and `3.2`, it is recommended to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. my versions are `0.10.0
and 3.1.3`

Comment: You might try changing 'blue' for some other color. E.g. 'dodgerblue' or 'navy'. Or, as a test just change the order of the colors to see what's happening either with 'blue' or with the last color of the list.